# What does leveling Jack up actually do?

Tags: mary-skelter-nightmares

In Mary Skelter: Nightmares, you technically play as Jack. Incidentally, Jack is the one party member who does not participate in combat and instead is the only one who can use items or spend his turn acting as a human shield for the other party members. However, after battle, he receives experience and levels up like everyone else, though, *unlike* the rest of the party members, Jack shows no stat gains (he doesn't even appear to *have* stats) or ability unlocks.

That said, does leveling Jack up actually *do* anything or is it just there for consistency's sake?

Comment: I guess it's there to factor in his survivability when taking a hit. I don't see any other purpose.